# Django queryset date filter based on subelement

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following Django models:

```
class Table(models.Model):
# model fields

    @property
    def is_finished(self):
        return not Meal.objects.filter(table=self)\
            .filter(finished_time=None).exists()

class Meal(models.Model):
    table = models.ForeignKey(
        Table,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='meals'
    )
    finished_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

A table is considered finished if all meals for it have a finished_time.
I would like to annotate is_finished in a queryset, to exclude tables where are meals are finished.

Something like:

```
Table.objects.all()\
    .annotate(has_meals=Count('meals__finished_time'))\
    .annotate(finished=Min('meals__finished_time'))\
    .filter(finished=None)\
    .exclude(has_meals=0)
```

But this does not work if I have finished meals and unfinished meals on a table.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an [Exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) subquery.

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef
Table.objects.all().annotate(
    is_finished=~Exists(
        Meal.objects.filter(table=OuterRef('id'), finished_time__isnull=True)
    )
)
```

The `~` flips the Exists value. To determine if there are any finished this will look to see if there any unfinished meals left, then flip it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, way easier than I thought it would be (once again)